# Rename portion of a directory

Tags: bash, shell, directory, rename

I am working on a sanitization process that takes IP address octets (in most cases the first two or three) & replaces them with a mask variable.

For example:

```
192.168.100.10 = xxx.yyy.zzz.10
```

This is pretty easy to do for files containing this txt (thank you sed), but I need to do this for directories as well.

My question is (without installing any extra perl packages, etc.) what is the best way to find a folder that contains a full ip & address & only the masked portion gets replaced.

For example:

```
/logs/folder/192.168.100.10/data -> /logs/folder/xxx.yyy.zzz.10/data
```

Where source IP octets = $IP & the mask values = $IMASK

Comment: Have you looked at `find` with a 1-line helper script to perform the *substring replacement* and the `mv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't consider the `find` command an *extra package*, you can do exactly what you want to do with `find` and a `while` loop, or `find` and a short one line helper script **so long as** `IP` only appears **once** in any given path hierarchy.

Utilizing a `find` and `while` loop along with *substring replacement*, you can do something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

srchdir="$1"

export ip=192.168.100
export mask=xxx.yyy.zzz
while read -r line; do
    mv "$line" "${line/$ip/$mask}"
done < <(find "$srchdir" -type d -name "*$ip*")
```

**Example**

With a temporary directory `td` containing the following:

```
$ tree td
td
├── 192.168.100.10
│   └── data
└── 192.168.100.20
    └── data

$ bash maskip.sh td
$ tree td
td
├── xxx.yyy.zzz.10
│   └── data
└── xxx.yyy.zzz.20
    └── data
```

Using `find` along with `-exec` and a short one-line helper script, `find` will complain that you have rearranged its results tree with your script, but will perform the requested operation. To get rid of the warning from `find`, you can simply redirect the output to `/dev/null`. Using the same `td` example (and with the same results) you can do:

```
$ ip=192.168.100; mask=xxx.yyy.zzz; \
find td -type d -name "*${ip}*" \
-exec ./helper.sh '{}' "$ip" "$mask" \; >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The helper script being nothing more than:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv "$1" "${1/$2/$3}"
```

Note, the `rename` command is also available, but depending upon whether you have the implementation from `util-linux` of not, the usages are completly different.

Look both over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to utilize your first example & integrate the concepts into what I had already created.  This worked great!!  Btw, a lawyer & an engineer!?  Very interesting combination! :)  thanks again!!

Comment: Yes, lawyer and engineer - perfect setup for bipolar-by-education disorder. I was actually arbitrating a case between two ISP's Friday where a lot of the issues involved in the claims surrounded manipulation of Platypus ISP billing software and the MSSQL backend, so understanding the technical aspects was a definite plus. Glad you were able to find some help in the post. Good luck with your scripting.